# Delete lines from input files excluding patterns listed in another file which may be empty in some cases?

Tags: regex, perl, perl-module

Scenerio1:

File1 : (file length will vary, may be sometimes empty file)

```
exclude1
exclude2  
exclude3
```

File2:

```
statement1 that has no excludes
statement2 that has exclude3
statement3 that has no excludes
statement4 that has no excludes
statement5 that has exclude1
statement6 that has exclude2
statement7 that has no excludes
```

output:

```
statement1 that has no excludes
statement3 that has no excludes
statement4 that has no excludes
statement7 that has no excludes
```

Scenerio2:

File1 : (empty file)

```
empty file
```

File2:

```
statement1 that has no excludes
statement2 that has no excludes
statement3 that has no excludes
statement4 that has no excludes
```

output:

```
statement1 that has no excludes
statement2 that has no excludes
statement3 that has no excludes
statement4 that has no excludes
```

script:

```
open (IN58, "<file2.txt") or die;
open (IN59, "<file1.txt") or die;
open (OUT42, ">output.txt") or die;
my @excludes = <IN59>;
chomp @excludes;
my $excludes = join ' |',@excludes;
while (<IN58>) {
next if /${excludes}/;
print OUT42 $_ ;
}
close (IN58);
close (IN59);
close (OUT42);
```

This script is working fine for scenario1, when exclude file (i.e. file1) becomes empty, its generating empty output file and not working as i wish. Any correction in the code is highly helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Here i have used the negative grep in order to extract the matches from a file, here `if condition` is used to check whether the file is empty or not.

If the file is empty the condition is not satisfied, so the values in `@br` won't change. If the condition is satisfied the values in `@br` are replaced by new values.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
open my $fh1, "<", "f1.txt" or die"$!";
my @ar = <$fh1>;
my $exculed = join("|",@ar);
$exculed=~ s/\n|\s//g;   #your input have some spaces so i used substitution instead of chomp

open my $fh2, "<", "f2.txt";
open my $nw, ">", "newfile.txt";
my @br = <$fh2>;
@br = grep{!/$exculed/g} @br if ($exculed ne "");
print $nw @br;
```

Comment: Though this logic works for other designs, its not working when exclude word is DFN1C1 and File2 lines are as follows in single line upto ); \po[6]\ : DFN1C1 port map(D => \po[5]_net_1\, CLK => CLK16M_c, CLR => \int_boardsel\, Q => \po[6]_net_1); v13_D_9_pad : OUTBUF port map(D => v13_D_9_c, PAD => v13_D_9);

Comment: @sumathigokul remove the $ from regex and try it, post edited

Answer (score 2):

The trick here is in being efficient about your test for exclusions - the way you can do this is by building a regular expression from your keywords, and then 'reject' any lines that 'match' at all.

So:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @excludes = qw ( exclude1
    exclude2
    exclude3 );

my $exclude_regex = join( "|", map {quotemeta} @excludes );
$exclude_regex = qr/$exclude_regex/;


while (<DATA>) {
    print unless /$exclude_regex/;
}


__DATA__
statement1 that has no excludes
statement2 that has exclude3
statement3 that has no excludes
statement4 that has no excludes
statement5 that has exclude1
statement6 that has exclude2
statement7 that has no excludes
```

Now, the problem here is of course - an empty 'match' will match anything, so effectively - you 'wildcard' your matches at that point. (and exclude everything).

The easiest way of handling this, is by inserting a 'default' pattern, which never matches - a blank line for example:

```
my $exclude_regex = join( "|", '^$', map {quotemeta} (  @excludes ) ) ;
```

This will filter blank lines *and* anything which has one of your exclude words, generating a regex like:

```
(?^:^$|exclude1|exclude2|exclude3)
```

To add in the file reading bit:

```
!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open( my $data,     '<', "file2.txt" )  or die;
open( my $excludes, '<', "file1.txt" )  or die;
open( my $output,   '>', "output.txt" ) or die;

chomp( my @excludes = <$excludes> );
my $exclude_regex = join( "|", '^$', map {quotemeta} (@excludes) );
$exclude_regex = qr/$exclude_regex/;
print $exclude_regex, "\n";

select $output;
while (<$data>) {
    print unless m/$exclude_regex/;
}
```

And as you seem to have a space in your 'regex assembly' you might want to consider changing the exclude regex to:

```
$exclude_regex = qr/\b$exclude_regex\b/;
```

Which will include word boundaries in the pattern matching (although you will then slightly break the 'empty line' match, and it won't match any more - but it will still work as a placeholder).

Whilst we're here

- 3 argument open with lexical filehandles are good,
- `use strict;` `use warnings;` should be considered mandatory.
- Consider what happens if your exclude file contains regex metacharacters. That's why `quotemeta` is in there, to treat them as literals.... but you might find it useful to support regex in your exclude file.

Comment: Nice answer! I liked the idea of the default pattern.